# iText - interactive redaction of existing PDF in browser

Tags: java, pdf, itext

In your example [How to remove text from a PDF](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-remove-text-pdf) you show how to remove text in a specific area of a PDF document by passing a pre-defined rectangle to PdfCleanUpLocation, but... where do the rectangle coordinates come from?

I have an existing PDF file on my web server that I need to interact with in a web browser. How can I determine the coordinates of a specific area of the document?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not possible with iText. You need a custom viewer that allows end users viewing the PDF in their browser to interact with the PDF. iText isn't such a viewer. iText lives only on the server, not on the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond to my question. I am looking at using pdf.js for this purpose. If I can just capture mouse events over the viewport, I can figure out the coordinates. If I can get them server-side, I can pass them to iText.